# Pycharm Not Stepping into Function

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm attempting to step through some Python code in Pycharm

`checkdata = cache.get_doc_store().get_all_documents(doc_type='test'})`

However, I can't seem to get Pycharm to step into this particular function. If I run it in the expression evaluator, the code executes and I get a return value, but if I try to run it in the standard debugger, Pycharm won't step into the function and I don't get a return value. Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: is it in your pythonpath?

Comment: Yep, it's in the Python path

Comment: then its likely a bug mate. report it on youtrack.

Comment: Running in command line we can't get it to fire off either

Comment: Are you connecting to the process through pycharm?

Comment: Yeah but we ran solely in terminal (i.e. invoked with python <myfile>)

Comment: Then its very much likely a bug.

Comment: A Pycharm bug? I think the code is fine, hypothetically if there was an issue with the code, we would have seen an exception thrown, or SOMETHING

Comment: Yes, a pycharm bug, I'm pretty sure there's no problem with your code.

Comment: The behavior is the same in the terminal though?

Answer (score 10):

So this one was actually related to generator functions. The return value I was getting was a `generator`, which I confused for the list generator `[x for x in func_call]`. When we "called" the function, we simply got a generator back, but the code in the function body is not executed until we call `next()`, `send()`, etc. Which is why we couldn't step into it in Pycharm. This blog post explains generators in much better detail https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/